# Compiling C and assembling ASM into machine code

Tags: c, assembly, compilation, machine-code

**I have three questions:**

1. What compiler can I use and how can I use it to compile C source code into **machine code**?
2. What assembler can I use and how can I use it to assemble ASM to **machine code**?
3. (optional) How would you recommend placing machine code in the proper addresses (i.e. bootloader machine code must be placed in the boot sector)?

**My goal:**
I'm trying to make a basic operating system. This would use a personally made bootloader and kernel. I would also try to take bits and pieces from the Linux kernel (namely the drivers) and integrate them into my kernel. I hope to create a 32-bit DOS-like operating system for messing with memory on most modern computers. I don't think I will be creating a executable format for my operating system, as my operating system wont be dynamic enough to require it.

**My situation:**
I'm running on a x86-64 windows 8 laptop with a Intel Celeron CPU; I believe it uses secure boot. I would be testing my operating system on a x86-64 desktop with Intel Core I3 CPU. I have a average understanding of operating systems and their techniques. I know the C, ASM, and computer theory required for this project. I think it is also note worthy that I'm sixteen with no formal education about computer science.

**My research:** After searching Google for what C normally compiles into, I found answers ranging from machine code, binary, plain binary, raw binary, assembly, and relocatable object code. Assembly as I understand normally assembles into a PE formatted executable. I have heard of the Cygwin, GCC C, and MingW C compilers. As for assemblers, I have heard of FASM, MASM, and NASM. I have searched websites such as [OSDev](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) and [OSDever](http://www.osdever.net/).

**What I have tried:** I tried to setup GCC (a nightmare) and create a cross compiler (another nightmare).

**Conclusion:** As you can tell, I'm vary confused about compilers, assemblers, and executable formats. Please dispel my ignorance along with answering my questions. These are probably the only things keeping me from having a OS on my resume. Sorry, I would have included more links, but stackoverflow wouldn't let me make more then two. Thanks a ton!

Comment: This project is quite probably a step too far. Right now you should set your sights lower and work up to this.

Comment: All you need is a plain GCC with a normal toolchain (ld in particular), not a cross-compiler tool-chain. See http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones

Comment: "What compiler can I use and how can I use it to compile C source code into machine code?" - any.
"What assembler can I use and how can I use it to assemble ASM to machine code?" - any. The purpose of these tools, by definition, is what you described.

Comment: making a gcc cross compiler is quite trivial actually.  getting one already built is even easier.  You are a long way from an "operating system"  bare metal sure, but not so far as an os.  Start with qemu or any other instruction set simulator, microcontroller, etc.  something you can get started with bare metal programming learn the tools then work your way up.  You are a long way from porting linux drivers to another platform until you get these basics down.

Comment: http://github.com/dwelch67/raspberrypi then look in the bare metal directory and databss directory (I also have a build_gcc or some such repo at github, with very simple scripts for cross compiling gcc for a number of platforms)...  Although these are non-x86 the same applies to any target using gcc, your best bet.  x86 is a horrible platform to start this kind of thing, I would avoid it, having the hardware is a bad excuse to use x86 for this kind of thing, get your experience in a simulator where you have more of a chance at success (better visibility) and less likely to quit in frustration

Comment: http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/

Answer (score 7):

First, some quick answers to your three questions.

1. Pretty much any compiler will translate C code into assembly code.  That's what compilers *do*.  GCC and clang are popular and free.

   ```
   clang -S -o example.s example.c
   ```
2. Whichever compiler you choose will probably support assembly as well, simply by using the same compiler driver.

   ```
   clang -o example.o example.s
   ```
3. Your linker documentation will tell you how to put specific code at specific addresses and so forth.  If you use GCC or clang as described above, you will probably use `ld(1)`.  In that case, read into 'linker scripts'.

Next, some notes:

- You don't need a cross compiler or to set up GCC by yourself.  You're working on an Intel machine, generating code for an Intel machine.  Any binary distribution of clang or GCC that comes with your linux distribution should work fine.
- C compilers normally compile code into assembly, and then pass the resulting assembly off to a system assembler to end up with machine code.  Machine code, binary, plain binary, raw binary, are all basically synonymous.
- The generated machine code is packaged into some kind of executable file format, to tell the host operating system how to load and run the code.  On windows, it's PE, on Linux, it's ELF, and on Mac OS X it's Mach-O.
- You don't need to create an executable format for your OS, but you will probably want to *use* one.  ELF is a pretty straightforward (and well-documented) option.

And a bit of a personal note that I hope doesn't discourage you too much - If you are not *very* familiar with how compilers, assemblers, linkers, and all of those tools work, your project is going to be *very* difficult and confusing.  You might want to start with some smaller projects to get your "sea legs", so to speak.

Answer (score 2):

At first "machine code" and "binary" are synonyms. "Object code" is some kind of intermediate form, that the linker will convert to binary at the end. Some C/C++ compilers generate not directly binary, but assembler source code, that they feed to the assembler, that produces object code and then to the linker, that makes the final binary. In the most cases these processes are transparent to the user. You feed the compiler with C/C++/Pascal/whatever source code and get a binary file at the output.

[FASM assembler, aka flatassembler](http://flatassembler.net) is the best assembler for OS development. There are several OSes already created in FASM.

That is because FASM is self compilable and is very easy portable. This way, for 2..3 days, you can port it to your OS and then your OS will become self sufficient - i.e. you will be able to compile the programs from within your OS.

Another good feature of FASM is that it does not need linker - it can generate directly binary files in several formats.

The big active community is also very important. There are tons of sources available for FASM, including for OS development.

The [message board](http://board.flatassembler.net) is very active and is place where one can learn a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I think the first part of your question has been answered, so I'll take on the other two:

> What assembler can I use and how can I use it to assemble ASM to machine code?

One of `nasm`, `yasm` (basically very like `nasm`), `fasm`, "masm" i.e. `ml64.exe`, `ml.exe` and freely available as part of the Microsoft tools.

Of these, I probably recommend either `nasm` or `yasm`. That recommendation is based entirely on personal preference - but the wide range of platforms they support, plus using Intel syntax by default are my reasons. I'd try a few and see what you like.

> (optional) How would you recommend placing machine code in the proper addresses (i.e. bootloader machine code must be placed in the boot sector)?

Well, there is only one way to place the bootloader at the correct address for MBR - open the disk at LBA 0 and write exactly 512 bytes there, ending in `0x55AA`. Flush, then close. The MBR usually also contains a partition table embedded in it - it is both code and data. The sciency term for this stuff is [Von Neumann Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture#Development_of_the_stored-program_concept) which can be briefly summarised as "programs and data are stored in the same place". The action of the BIOS on wanting to boot from disk will be to read the first 512 bytes into memory, check the signature and if it matches, execute that memory (starting from byte 0).

OK, that's those questions out of the way. Now I'll give you some more notes:

- 512-bytes for a bootloader is not really enough for anyone's usage. As such, some file systems contain boot sectors and the bootloader itself simply loads the code/data found in these. This allows for larger amounts of code to be loaded - enough to get a kernel going. For example, grub contains stage1, stage1_5 and stage2 components in the legacy version.
- Although most operating systems require you to use an executable format container, you don't *need* one. On disk and in memory, executable code is just one, two or three byte strings called opcodes. You can read [the opcode reference](http://ref.x86asm.net/) or the Intel/AMD manuals to find out what hexadecimal value translates to what. Anyway, you can perform a direct conversion from assembler to binary using nasm like this:

  ```
   nasm -f bin input.asm -o output.asm
  ```

  Which will work for 16, 32 or 64 bit assembler quite happily although the result likely won't execute. The only place it will is if you explicitly use the `[bits 16]` directive in your code, along with `org 100h`, then you have an MSDOS .com program. Unfortunately, this is the simplest of binary formats in existence - you only have code and data in one big lump and this must not exceed the size of a single segment.

  I feel this might handle this point:

  > I found answers ranging from machine code, binary, plain binary, raw binary, assembly, and relocatable object code.

  The answer as to what assembly assembles to - it assembles to opcodes and memory addresses, depending on the assembler. This is represented in bytes which are data all of themselves. You can read them raw with a hex editor although there are few occasions where this is strictly necesary. I mention memory addresses because some opcodes control how memory addresses are interpreted - relocatable object code for example requires that addresses are not hard-coded (instead, they are interpreted as offsets from the current location).

  > Assembly as I understand normally assembles into a PE formatted executable.

  It is fair to say the assembler from which your C/C++ was derived is compiled to opcodes which are then, along with anything else to be included in the program (data, resources) are stored in an executable format, such as PE. Normally depends on your OS.
- If you have thoroughly read the OSDev Wiki, you'll realise segmented addressing is an utter pain - the standard and only usage of segments in modern operating systems is to define four segments spanning the entire address space - two data segments at ring 0 and 3, two code segments at ring 0 and 3.
- If you haven't read [the OSDEV Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org) thoroughly, you should. I'd also recommend [JamesM's kernel tutorials](http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/index.html) which contain practical advice on building a kernel in C.
- If you simply want to do bad things to a DOS kernel, you actually still can without needing to write a full kernel yourself. You should also be able to switch the CPU to protected mode from DOS, too. You need [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/) and an assembler of your choice. There is an excellent tutorial on [terminate and stay resident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminate_and_Stay_Resident) which basically means hooking an interrupt routine, then editing yourself out of the active process list, in [The Rootkit Arsenal](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/144962636X). There are probably tutorials on the internet for this, too.

  I might be tempted to recommend doing this as a first, just to get yourself used to this kind of low level stuff.
- If you just wanted to poke an OS, you can set up kernel debugging on Windows. WinDbg is a bit... arcane, but once you get used to it it makes sense.
- You mention your laptop uses secure boot. If this is the case your laptop uses UEFI. If you want to read up on this, the [UEFI spec](http://www.uefi.org/specs/) is 100% guaranteed more boring than your maths homework, but I recommend skimming it just to understand the goals and the basic environment. THe important thing is to have the [EFI SDK](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/tianocore/index.php?title=UDK2010) which enables you to build EFI-compatible applications (which are in PE format and exist on a FAT32 partition on your disk - so installing an EFI bootloader is very simple even if writing one is not so. If I had to make an honest recommendation, I'd stick to MBR for now, since emulating OSes with MBR is much easier than EFI at the time of writing and *you really do want to do this in some form of VM for now*. Also, I'd use an existing one like grub, since bootloaders are not all that exciting, really.
- Others have said it, and I will say it: *You absolutely want to do anything like this under some form of emulator or virtual machine*. You will make a mistake, guaranteed, and you will come up against things you don't understand. Emulators and VM software are free these days, and some such as BOCHS will tell you what the reason for a given fault, trap etc is. This is massively helpful!

Answer (score 0):

First,  use something like Virtual box for your testing

I think you might want to take some smaller steps, get comfortable writing C code.

then look into how boot sectors on disks work  ( well documented on the internet)  also look at code of other open source boot loaders.

Then look at how to do task switching.  Its not too hard to write.  You can even write most of it while running it under your normal OS before trying to embeded into your own OS

With C compilers you can generally mix in asm inline usually with `asm { /* assembly code */ }`